# Change prompt on command line?

Tags: fish

My prompt is quite verbose - which is good most of the time - but now I would like to switch it temporarily because I want to make a screen shot of the terminal. For that purpose I would prefer not to delve into config files but to set the prompt just quickly to something short like ">" and then restore it.

Is that possible with fish shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

1. `funced fish_prompt`
2. at the top of the function add the line

   ```
   echo '> '; return
   ```

   and save
3. screen capture
4. to restore your prompt, `funced fish_prompt` and remove the inserted line.

Answer (score 0):

If you install [oh-my-fish](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish) then you can switch themes quickly:

```
$ omf theme <installed_theme_name>
```

Here is an example:

[image]